# Item pending in cart for more than 15 min then which event to trigger in magento 2

Tags: magento2, event-observer, shopping-cart, magento-2.1.7

I want to **trigger an event when in cart**, items are pending for **more than 15 minutes**.
Can anyone pls guide me how to do?

Answer (score 0):

Magento gives some of the default events for the cart.

> Stores > Configuration > Customers > Persist Shopping Cart

From above path, you can configure that events with the specific time...

Comment: How to configure events? Pls explain it briefly.

Comment: Which event do you want to configure? Please explain so I can guide you

Comment: I want to send sms to customer if products are in cart for more than 15 min. Can you pls tell me which event I should fire for that.

Comment: For that, you need to customization.

Comment: ok, how to customise?